# Get name of maven pom file

Tags: maven-2, properties

I am running a Maven (2) release build with with: `mvn -f release.xml clean deploy`
and want to get the currently running pom file name (`release.xml`) into a property or mojo.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can use the property

`${env.MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS}`

in your pom or a filtered resource, which will expand to something like

`clean install -Paxis -Dmaven.test.skip -f mypom.xml -pl util`

however, if you just want the mypom.xml part, you're going to have to do some scripting, which is not supported out of the box in maven. Common solutions are either [maven antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) or [gmaven (groovy) plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home). Here's a way to do it in gmaven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                System.out.println(
                        System
                        .getenv("MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS")
                        .replaceFirst( /.*\-f\s+(\S+).*/ , 'POM File: $1')
                    );
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

Edit: as you want it in a property, either use System.setProperty or write directly to `project.properties`